# Enzyme Specificity vs Selectivity

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

**Background**:
I can see a difference in stereoselective and stereospecific reactions in organic chemistry. However, both terms are used interchangeably as synonyms in a biochemistry class.

**Question**:
What differs selectivity from specificity in enzymatic reactions. What is meant when we talk about enzyme specificity and enzyme selectivity?

Answer (score 4):

Specificity is the term used to define the selectivity of enzymes
for their substrates. The selective qualities of an enzyme are collectively recognized as its specificity.

Other [texts](http://chromogenicsubstrates.com/tech/chromogenic_substrates_basic_specificity.htm) have synonymised **enzyme selectivity** with s**ubstrate specificity**:

> The non-covalent forces through which substrates and other molecules bind to enzymes are similar in character to the forces
> that dictate the conformations of the proteins themselves : Both involve van der Waals, electrostatic, hydrogen
> bonding, and hydrophobic interactions.
> Molecules that differ in shape or functional group distribution
> from the substrate cannot productively bind to the
> enzyme; that is, they cannot form enzyme–substrate complexes
> that lead to the formation of products.

The extraordinary ability of an enzyme to catalyse only one particular reaction is a quality known as **specificity**.

Specificity means an enzyme acts only on a specific substance,
its substrate, invariably transforming it into a specific product. That is, an enzyme
binds only certain compounds, and then, only a specific reaction ensues.
Some enzymes show absolute specificity, catalyzing the transformation of only one
specific substrate to yield a unique product. Other enzymes carry out a particular
reaction but act on a class of compounds. For example, hexokinase (ATP-hexose-6-
phosphotransferase) will carry out the ATP-dependent phosphorylation of a number
of hexoses at the 6-position, including glucose.

> Pioneering enzyme specificity studies at the turn of the 20th century
> by the great organic chemist Emil Fischer led to the notion of an
> enzyme resembling a “lock” and its particular substrate the “key.”
> *The specificity of an enzyme (the lock) for its substrate (the key) arises from their geometrically complementary shapes.* This was later
> modified to a more accurate *induced fit hypothesis* given the high
> flexibility, conformationally dynamic properties of enzyme molecules.

**References**

1. Voet and Voet Biochemistry 4th ed: Introduction to Enzymes
2. Biochemistry Grisham & Garret How Can Enzymes Be So Specific?

Answer (score 2):

Selectivity is used when talking about the substrate, for example an enzyme can be more selective for D- sugars compared to L-sugars.

Specificity is used when talking about the product. For example an enzyme that only accepts a single compound could specifically hydroxylate the 2 position, even though there are be more positions that could be hydroxylated.